# Teradata : Which dbc table contains the ACCOUNT field?

Tags: teradata

I need to find out what is my `account` . I looked at the following tables :

```
dbc.accounts 
DBC.AccountInfoV
DBC.ProfileInfo
```

They have the `accountname`, which is not the same . WHere can I find my account ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your currently active account can be retrieved using the built-in `ACCOUNT` function:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT;
```

Your default account is returned by:

```
SELECT DefaultAccount
FROM dbc.UsersV
WHERE UserName = USER;
```

And the list of all accounts your user might use, assigned either to the user directly or via the user's profile:

```
SELECT AccountName
FROM dbc.accountinfoVX
WHERE (PROFILE IS NULL AND USERNAME = USER)
   OR (USERNAME = PROFILE)
```